# Scrape a website asynchronously using a list of tor circuits

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, tor

I want to scrape a website asynchronously using a list of tor circuits with different exit nodes and making sure each exit node only makes a request every 5 seconds.

For testing purposes, I'm using the website https://books.toscrape.com/ and I'm lowering the sleep time, number of circuits and number of pages to scrape.

I'm getting the following two errors when I use the `--tor` argument. Both related to the torpy package.

```
'TorWebScraper' object has no attribute 'circuits'
'_GeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'create_stream'
```

Here is the relevant code causing the error:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    for circuit in self.circuits:
        async with circuit.create_stream() as stream:
            async with session.get(url, proxy=stream.proxy) as response:
                await asyncio.sleep(20e-3)
                text = await response.text()
                return url, text
```

[Here there is more context](https://git.disroot.org/hirrolot19/AO3Scraper/src/commit/dc24baaf15996be7848645fb282f66b67ec32b45/extras/web_scraper.py)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is being caused by the fact that your code starts asyncio loop on object init which is not a good practice:

```py
class WebScraper(object):
    def __init__(self, urls: List[str]):
        self.urls = urls
        self.all_data = []
        self.master_dict = {}
        asyncio.run(self.run())
        #^^^^^^

class TorWebScraper(WebScraper):
    def __init__(self, urls: List[str]):
        super().__init__(urls)
        # ^^^^^ this already called run() from parent class
        self.circuits = get_circuits(3)
        asyncio.run(self.run())
        # ^^^^^ now run() is being called a second time
```

Ideally, to avoid issues like this you should leave the logic code to your classes and separate out the run code to your script. In other words, move `asyncio.run` to `asyncio.run(scrape_test_website())`.

Comment: [I fixed that](https://git.disroot.org/hirrolot19/AO3Scraper/src/commit/dc24baaf15996be7848645fb282f66b67ec32b45/extras/web_scraper.py), but I'm still getting the error `'_GeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'create_stream'`